# Understanding Swift flat map syntax

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

The syntax used for flatMap in function 'parseB' below uses parenthesis, rather than curly brackets.

```
struct Episode {
    let id: String
    let title: String
}

extension Episode {
    init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? String, title = dictionary["title"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
}

func parseA(dictionaries: [[String: AnyObject]]) -> [Episode] {
    return dictionaries.flatMap { dic in Episode.init(dictionary: dic)}
}

func parseB(dictionaries: [[String: AnyObject]]) -> [Episode] {
    return dictionaries.flatMap (Episode.init)
}
```

There is a flat map implementation that looks like so

```
public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U!) rethrows -> U!
```

Reading this I still can't understand how, in the above example, the init on Episodes has no parenthesis.

Sometimes Swift is so good at inferring stuff it's hard to read what is going on. Could someone help me understand why the init method for Episodes is not using parenthesis please ?

```
...flatMap (Episode.init)
```

Ref1: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E01-networking
Ref2: https://github.com/objcio/S01E01-networking

Comment: That's because [instance methods are curried functions in swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Employee {
    var name: String = ""

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

> Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift

**This is a curried function which takes a single argument String and return an Employee**

```
let employeeFunc = Employee.init  //  (String) -> Employee
```

**Lets define our own map function on Array Type**

```
extension Array {
    func myMap <U> (f: (Element) -> U) -> [U] {
        var result = [U]()

        for element in self {
            result.append(f(element))
        }
        return result
    }
}


var allEmployee = [Employee]()
let names = ["Mario", "Luigi"]
```

**You can pass value to curried function one at a time. This curried function only expect one argument**

```
let firstEmployee = employeeFunc("Superman")
```

**Similarly we can pass multiple name to multiple Employee to create instances**

```
allEmployee = names.myMap(f: employeeFunc)
```

**We can map like this also**

```
allEmployee = names.myMap(){ employeeFunc($0)}
```

**Lets print the value**

```
for employee in allEmployee {
    print (employee.name)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with a simple code snippet

```
[1,2,3].map(String.init) // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Here `map` iterates over each element of the array [1,2,3] and each time pass the n-th element to the `String` initializer.

This works because

1. the array has `Int` as generic element
2. `String` has an init accepting `Int` as only parameter

### Why the `( ... )` instead of `{ ... }` ?

In this case we use this `.map(...)` instead of this `.map{ ... }` because we are passing to `map` a function defined elsewhere (well an initializer) and we are not directly writing the function/closure.

It's like when we write

```
func isEven(n:Int) -> Bool {
    return n % 2 == 0
}

[1,2,3].filter(isEven) // [2]
```

Here we are passing to filter the function defined above so we use `()`.

Of course we can also write the function directly using `{ ... }`

```
[1,2,3].filter { (n:Int) -> Bool in
    return n % 2 == 0
}
```

### Your code

In your code this works

```
dictionaries.flatMap (Episode.init)
```

because `Episode` has an `init` that accepts the same type of the elements in `dictionaries`.

Infact each element of `dictionaries` has this type `[String: AnyObject]` and the init of Episode accepts the same type.

```
init?(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because in Swift, [instance methods are curried functions](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/). Which means that `Episode.init` is a function (actually it's a named closure) which receives one argument - `self`, which coincidentally (or not) matches the signature of the closure that `flatMap` expects.

What happens in your code is that you're passing a reference to a closure that `flatMap` expects, rather than calling it, as calling the closure will just return you an `Episode` instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is **Trailing Closures swift** you can find it in apple documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

`flatMap` waits something as parameter with type `(A)->B`, but it can be function or closure:

```
let initializer: (Int) -> String = String.init
```

same

```
let closure:(Int) -> String = {return String($0)}
```

For simplicity we can call `map` method:

```
[1,2,3].map(initializer) == [1,2,3].map(closure)
```

but if we use closure is last parameter, it can be written outside of the method, in our case `map` method

```
[1,2,3].map(){return String($0)}
```

more than we can omit `()`:

```
[1,2,3].map{return String($0)}
```